# My object element wont show 100% height

Tags: html, css

I am making an *accordion menu* whereby I am adding a *PDF inside an object element*. However I just cannot get the object to **show 100% of its height**, therefore it makes it difficult to use.

All I would like is to know how to make the PDF file inside of the object div to show it's full height. I remember having similar issues with footers..

Thanks.

```js
if( jQuery(".toggle .toggle-title").hasClass('active') ){
  jQuery(".toggle .toggle-title.active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').show();
}

jQuery(".toggle .toggle-title").click(function(){
  if( jQuery(this).hasClass('active') ){
    jQuery(this).removeClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').slideUp(200);
  } else {  
    jQuery(this).addClass("active").closest('.toggle').find('.toggle-inner').slideDown(200);
  } 
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #4B4B4B;
  font-family: ARIMO;
}
body a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #4B4B4B;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body section {
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
body section h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

object{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Styles for Accordion */

.toggle{
  background: #eee;
  border-top: solid 1px #3b7c8e;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}

.toggle .toggle-title {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.toggle .toggle-title h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.toggle .toggle-inner {
  padding: 7px 25px 10px 25px;
  display: none;
  margin: -7px 0 6px;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.toggle .toggle-inner div {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.toggle .toggle-title{
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 25px 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="toggle-title">
    <h3>
      <div class="title-name">Example title</div>
    </h3>
    <p>Example call for paper</p>
    <p>Astronomers face an embarrassing conundrum: they don't know what 95% of the universe is made of. Atoms, which form everything we see around us, only account for a measly 5%. Over the past 80 years it has become clear that the substantial remainder is comprised of two shadowy entities – dark matter and dark energy. The former, first discovered in 1933, acts as an invisible glue, binding galaxies and galaxy clusters together. Unveiled in 1998, the latter is pushing the universe's expansion to ever greater speeds. Astronomers are closing.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle-inner">
    <object height="100" data="http://prototypes.infopro-insight.com/test/MW/call_for_papers.pdf"></object>
  </div>
</div><!-- END OF TOGGLE -->
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to get this object to automatically adapt its height to the height of the PDF (by whatever metric, based on PDF “page height”) …? That is close to impossible, I think. You would need a scripting solution that actually “understands PDF”, and can analyze the specific PDF in that regard. (Perhaps not totally impossible, but presumably rather complex.)

Comment: Yes that is what I need I think, I didn't know that it would be this complex